# Can't parse json response from laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, server, http-headers

There is such problem with headers. In PHP:

```
return response()->json([ 'somedata' => 1 ]);
```

In JS:

```
$.get('/page', function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json

{"somedata":"1"}
```

Yes, its a plain text. Why response contain headers? And of course i can't parse that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - return type in php7.

```
public function index() : string {
    return response()->json([ 'somedata' => 1 ]);
}
```

Without `: string` everything is okay!